# How can you account for number of likes over time in research on instagram success?

Tags: time-series

I have a dataset, from 2013 to 2019, containing posts (with some variables), including comments on those posts, the amount of likes and the amount of comments. I want to predict the 'success' of a post. For this I make a regression model on likes, comments and a ratio of both.

Now I want to know how to account for data over years. Since there is a clear relationship between the year of the post and the amount of likes/comments (2013 has way less comments and likes since back then the account was less popular).

At the moment we would account for this by looking at likes or comments per follower.

Comment: Just add the year as a variable?

Comment: @GermanDemidov How does year have a predictive power? If I would add year as a variable, run a regression, the variable year will have a high coefficient, whilst it has no predictive power.

Comment: "Since there is a clear relationship between the year of the post and the amount of likes/comments" vs "whilst it has no predictive power." - I think there is a contradiction here =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could adjust for the expected activity.

One way to do it would be to find the average number of posts/likes/whatevs and, instead of predicting based on the *number* of them, predict based on the number/avg. number.

So, for instance, if in 2005, the average likes for *everyone* was 100, and someone got 130 - your feature is $130/100 = 1.3$, pretty good. But in 2008, it was 1000, so $130/1000 = 0.13$, not so great.

A subtler approach would be to adjust on probabilities directly, which would let you account for the asymmetry inherent in that kind of thing, and for the fact your data is discrete, but that's a little bit more complicated, so I won't go into it unprompted.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use this. Is there any documentation or name related to this method and/or the subtler approach?

Comment: Well, the first thing is normalization/feature scaling, in the broader context of feature engineering - you probably care about anomalies more in terms of ratios, so it makes sense to use ratios as a feature, if you were curious whether some guy got 100 extra likes no matter if he had 0 or 10000, you'd use raw quantities by the same logic. The trickier approach I have in mind is a Hierarchical Bayes, basically assuming the parameters the distribution for one person is drawn from other distribution(s); Judea Pearl's probably a good starting point for that.